# Get root permission on android for metasploit

Tags: android, metasploit, permissions, whatsapp, root

Is there any way to get into the root file system in android with an already installed msfvenom apk in reverse_tcp (to get the whatsapp encryption key)

Comment: Unlock your bootloader and flash Magisk.

Comment: If and how a device can be rooted depends on the manufacturer and the phone model. Check out e.g. xda developer forums of your device to read more about rooting your device.